# Squad overwatch reaction

Tags: xcom-2

So in XCOM: Enemy Unknown and Enemy Within if an enemy NPC triggered overwatch every single person, who could see that target, would fire - even if they were killed.   Is the same true in XCOM 2?  I have been trying to keep my troops spread far apart for this very reason, and this poses it's own risks, so if I was able to keep people closer together then that would reduce some risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

In XCOM 2, soldiers on overwatch will attack one at a time and will not try to attack dead enemies.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to what order overwatching soldiers will activate in when many of them can see a triggering enemy at once? Based on my experience I suspect that the soldier with the best chance of hitting gets to go first, as my snipers usually seem to be the first to take shots.

Comment: @Carcer If I had to guess, it simply picks the first valid target, and the earliest possible shot. Your snipers go first because squadsight lets them see that much farther.

Comment: And this is wonderful change. A single enemy before could trigger the whole squad. Now the team can beat all enemies during single overwatch:)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: `Your snipers go first because squadsight lets them see that much farther.` Minor difference: squadsight inherently means that **another unit** can see the enemy (which is why the sniper sees them too). So if that unit is also on overwatch, he will shoot at the same time as the sniper (except for the whole "not shooting a dead enemy" thing of course).